# Plotting amplifier transfer characteristics

Tags: amplifier

Attempting to plot the transfer characteristics of a simple demonstration-kit amp. I reasoned if I extend from roughly equidistant points on both in/out signal, they should meet to represent a fairly correct result.  And since the out-signal is not symmetrical, there must be different response on a falling and rising signal, hence the two.

Would these plots be fairly correct, or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plot looks like a reasonable way to estimate transfer function.

Power Amps tend NOT to run in Class A unless they are RF, so the transfer function of each polarity signal is different with crossover design to merge and least amount of negative feedback to reduce distortion and extend bandwidth

But to design for better linearity, we need circuit details to ensure;

- bias current sink/source exceeds load current and
- output swing stays 2V away from saturation.
- analyze non-linear loads